# why every class is prefixed with "C" in Yii eg: CModel, CActiveRecord etc?

Tags: yii

why every class is prefixed with "C" in Yii eg: CModel, CActiveRecord etc ?
Is it a naming convention of yii or some thing related to components .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a naming convention for classes provided with the framework. Straight from the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace):

> Tip: Because PHP prior to 5.3.0 does not support namespace
>   intrinsically, you cannot create instances of two classes who have the
>   same name but with different definitions. For this reason, all Yii
>   framework classes are prefixed with a letter 'C' (meaning 'class') so
>   that they can be differentiated from user-defined classes. It is
>   recommended that the prefix 'C' be reserved for Yii framework use
>   only, and user-defined classes be prefixed with other letters.